# 404 returned from a file that exists in ASP.Net on IIS 5

Tags: http-status-code-404, iis-5

I'm running into this problem and its driving me crazy.

Also, we are not allowed to update the version of IIS.

The content on the server (asmx files holding WCF webmethods called via SOAP) exists and I can freely browse in inetmgr to the virtual directory that contains this data.  The files all exist all on the file system and the virtual directories all point to the correct spot and have the correct ACLS, but when I go to their URLs all I get is a 404 message.

I have reset IIS, I have rebooted the server, and I have done everything I can think of.

The IIS logs simple return "404 - -" as the entire line contents, with no other data in the line.

The event logs show nothing, and ASPNET is not dying or anything like that.

With no event logs, and minimal logs in IIS , I have no idea what to do and was hoping that others had run into this before.

Comment: 1.1.4322.0      Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\asp
net_isapi.dll
2.0.50727.0     Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\as
pnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0     Valid (Root)    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\as
pnet_isapi.dll

Comment: Also: If i just go to the URL and get the WSDL the link works fine and i am returned HTTP 200, but if I try a GET or POST against the link without a WSDL request it gives me a 404.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS logs there should some codes along side the 404 error which will help find the issue.

Check IIS has the correct version of .Net installed using `aspnet_regiis` command line tool. Also check that ASMX extensions are mapped to the .Net ISAPI filter as they are with ASPX pages.

Comment: Output of aspnet_regiis tool is:
1.1.4322.0      Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\asp
net_isapi.dll
2.0.50727.0     Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\as
pnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0     Valid (Root)    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\as
pnet_isapi.dll

IIS logs only contain:
18:15:07 127.0.0.1 - - 404
.. and no other data.

The .net module for asp version ASP.NET_4.0.30319.0 is registered.

Comment: Check if webservice GET requests are disabled, [see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267) for more info.